# AdWhirl and AdMob folder URL

Tags: iphone, admob, adwhirl

Where can I find/download the "Admob folder" referred to in the requirements of Adwhirl's support of Admob in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download that folder from AdMob (or whatever ad source you want to use). The different ad providers distribute their own API code and you have to include each of those libs in your project along with AdWhirl.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I found the AdMob site hard to navigate, so I asked a friend for the AdMob folder. I later found the AdMob SDK by accident on the AdMob site, buried somewhere. The question was asking for a specific URL, I was pretty sure it was on their site somewhere just no idea where!